# Woocommerce budget search

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I have woo commerce setup.
Now requirement is like say If I search budget lets say 5000,It should show products whose price total is 5000 (ex. one product of price 3000 & one product of  prize 2000 ).
How can we do that,Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you can apply a filter on products by passing URL query `www.mysite.com/shop/?min_price=0&max_price=5000`

Comment: here min_price and max_price are woocommerce's filter parameters.

Comment: This will give the products whose price ranges between 0 to 5000.But my question is different